# How to get former year using MDX expression

Tags: ssas, mdx

I've a working `MDX` query in a SSRS dataset, not done by me, that has the following lines inside it:

```
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pYear, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pMonth, CONSTRAINED) ) 
...
```

Everything works fine. However, **I need to duplicate this dataset to have another one with the same data but from the former year** (subtract one).

I've tried to modify it, got an error and then [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044966/the-restrictions-imposed-by-the-constrained-flag-were-violated) about `MDX` which I didn't know until now. However I've not been able to understand exactly how it works and how could I get the previous year. I've been reading a lot of docs, but examples are not being quite clear to me.

I have tried with the [Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/sum-mdx?view=sql-server-2017) function, but I wasn't able to make it work because all the examples that I found do start with a `with` clause that can't work in the middle of a query, plus these examples seem to use `members` but my query is using `sets` (if I don't misunderstand it).

I've tried using at the begining:

`MEMBER [Measures].[Ano Prev] AS SUM(STRTOMEMBER(@pYear) , -1)`

But then after that, I'm not able to use it in the lines like the previous ones.

How can I achieve it? (Insights and "how to" explanations would be greatly appreciated!)

### Update

Note that the `@pYear` from the question is translated as `@pEjercicio` in the query.

Complete original query:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Comision] AS [Measures].[Comision Once]*[Measures].[Importe] 

SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Importe], [Measures].[Unidades], [Measures].[N Tiendas], [Measures].[Comision Once] } ON COLUMNS, 


NON EMPTY { ([Tiempo].[Periodos].[Ano]*[Tiempo].[Meses].[Mes].ALLMEMBERS * [Productos].[Once Modalidad].[Once Modalidad].ALLMEMBERS ) } 


ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT (-{[Productos].[Cod-Producto].[Cod Producto].&[139972]} ) 


ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pEjercicio, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pMes, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pSemana, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( -{ [Productos].[Once Modalidad].&[-] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pOrganizacion, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pDirectorRegional, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pTecnicoComercial, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pCoordinadorComercial, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pTecnicoFranquicia, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM [Transacciones]))))))))))
```

Modified query based on answer:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Comision] AS [Measures].[Comision Once]*[Measures].[Importe] 
MEMBER [Measures].[Ano Prev] AS SUM((STRTOMEMBER(@pEjercicio).PrevMember) , -1)

SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Importe], [Measures].[Unidades], [Measures].[N Tiendas], [Measures].[Comision Once] } ON COLUMNS, 


NON EMPTY { ([Tiempo].[Periodos].[Ano]*[Tiempo].[Meses].[Mes].ALLMEMBERS * [Productos].[Once Modalidad].[Once Modalidad].ALLMEMBERS ) } 


ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT (-{[Productos].[Cod-Producto].[Cod Producto].&[139972]} ) 

ON COLUMNS FROM ( select ( 
STRTOSET(@pEjercicio, CONSTRAINED).item(0).prevmember,
STRTOSET(@pEjercicio, CONSTRAINED).item(1)  ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pMes, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pSemana, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( -{ [Productos].[Once Modalidad].&[-] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pOrganizacion, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pDirectorRegional, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pTecnicoComercial, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pCoordinadorComercial, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pTecnicoFranquicia, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM [Transacciones]))))))))))
```

Some profiler data:

```
<Parameters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
        <Parameter>
          <Name>pEjercicio</Name>
          <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">-1</Value>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
          <Name>pMes</Name>
          <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">[Tiempo].[Periodos].[Mes].&amp;[1]&amp;[2019]&amp;[TR-1]</Value>
        </Parameter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I solved it (with some colleague guidance) with a bit of workaround, since I first aimed to have a complete dataset of the previous year. However, **this solution targets only the desired values instead of a complete new dataset**.

The idea is to get the value as a `member` and then add it to `columns`.

Since I need to get it for the previous year (title of the question here), I have to use `parallelperiod` to get this year. The argument for this [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/parallelperiod-function-dax) is a positive `int` because it means a **lag**.

`MEMBER [Measures].[Your_Parameter_Previous_Year] AS ( PARALLELPERIOD( [Time].[Years].[Year] , 1 , [Time].[Years].CurrentMember ),[Measures].[Your_Parameter]  )`

If you need more than one value, you would need to prepare as many members as you need.

Then, you have to include it in the `select` like:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [ ...
[Measures].[Your_Parameter],
[Measures].[Your_Parameter_Previous_Year],
... }
```

And that's it. Now you have the values from the previous year in your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prevmember to solve the issue.

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Ano Prev] AS SUM((STRTOMEMBER(@pYear).PrevMember) , -1)

ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pYear, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pMonth, CONSTRAINED) )
```

in the above write the select as

```
select 
( 
STRTOSET(@pYear, CONSTRAINED).item(0).prevmember,
STRTOSET(@pYear, CONSTRAINED).item(1)
)
```

If the above doesnt work edit your question to show the text value of the expression

```
SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pYear, CONSTRAINED)
```

Based on the edit above
    WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Comision] AS [Measures].[Comision Once]*[Measures].[Importe]

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Importe], [Measures].[Unidades], [Measures].[N Tiendas], [Measures].[Comision Once] } ON COLUMNS, 


NON EMPTY { ([Tiempo].[Periodos].[Ano]*[Tiempo].[Meses].[Mes].ALLMEMBERS * [Productos].[Once Modalidad].[Once Modalidad].ALLMEMBERS ) } 


ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT (-{[Productos].[Cod-Producto].[Cod Producto].&[139972]} ) 


ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pEjercicio, CONSTRAINED).item(0).prevmember ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pMes, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pSemana, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( -{ [Productos].[Once Modalidad].&[-] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pOrganizacion, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pDirectorRegional, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pTecnicoComercial, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pCoordinadorComercial, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pTecnicoFranquicia, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM [Transacciones]))))))))))
```

Comment: I've tried it and although it complies with MDX syntax, on runtime I'm still getting the same error. I'm going to update with the full query and so on.

Comment: @BtcSources I would need the actual query that is passed to the server. You may want use profiler for that

Comment: Added profiler data about the parameter. There may be data that I cannot share in the other parameters so please let me know if you know specific data from the log!

Comment: @BtcSources I need the parameter value for the parameter which contains the year. I have doubts that "SELECT ( STRTOSET(@pEjercicio, CONSTRAINED)" this contians year as in the profiler data it showed -1.

Comment: I've managed to get the result that I wanted in a different way, thanks to a colleague help. I'll post it as an answer since it uses a different approach not modifying the `@pEjercicio` parameter.